# First Upload to SVN without Local Root Directory

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to take some code and do an initial commit to SVN (via TortoiseSVN on Windows 7).
My project is in a folder setup like this:

```
[Project]
 - [Libs]
 - [Main App]
```

I'm trying to upload to SVN via "Add Folder" to the trunk but everytime I do, what I get looks like:

```
[trunk]
 [Project]
  - [Libs]
  - [Main App]
```

But I would like it to look like:

```
[trunk]
 - [Libs]
 - [Main App]
```

I cannot figure out how to get it to do this on the first upload... I realize it's fairly trivial and I could probably change the name of my local directory to "trunk" and upload that to the SVN root, not the trunk, but I figure it has to be possible and I'm just missing something.

Any way this can be done?

Comment: As mentioned in @lazy's answer below, the key to reorganising subversion in explorer is to *right click* and drag, which then opens up TortoiseSVN/Git/Hg's VCS context menu, to move/copy etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Client-side solution**

- Checkout current repository *as is*
- Create in Working copy needed tree at root-level (trunk, branches, tags) - you'll see 4 directory in root after it
- D&D with **Right-Button on mouse** `Libs` and `Main App` from Project dir to trunk in WinExplorer, select "SVN Move" action
- Delete empty Project
- Commit, select all suggested files in commit

Use standard layout of repository

Answer (score 0):

Create the layout in the repository:

`svn mkdir REPO_URL/trunk REPO_URL/tags REPO_URL/branches -m "Layout creation."`

Import the source to trunk:

```
cd Project
svn import . REPO_URL/trunk -m "Initial import."
```

Or you could:

```
mkdir toimport
mv Project toimport/trunk
mkdir toimport/tags toimport/branches
cd toimport
svn import . REPO_URL -m "Initial import with layout."
```

Comment: Awesome, will give it a shot,,,  just curious, is there an equivalent in the GUI?

Comment: I would assume so but I dont use Tortoise/Windows so I cant say.